# Syntax Highlighting Needs Updating for C#

Tags: bug

Whilst generally good, the in-question syntax highlighting for `C#` seems to be gradually falling behind as new features are added to the language.

For instance, `C#6`'s string interpolation is not considered for syntax highlighting.

[image: String Interpolation Syntax Highlighting]

I believe that `{file}` should not be formatted as part of the string to make it clearer that it is interpolated at runtime (assuming the `$` token was present to indicate that the string should be interpolated).

I understand that this isn't the most pressing issue in the world but I wonder if anyone else thinks that issues like this should be addressed, especially considering the slew of features `C#7` is about to dump on us.

Comment: Please report issues with the highlighter to the code-prettify project; see the FAQ I duplicated this post to.